# In memory database with fallback to disk on OOM

Tags: python

I have lots of data to operate on (write, sort, read). This data can potentially be larger than the main memory and doesn't need to be stored permanently.

Is there any kind of library/database that can store these data for me in memory and that does have and automagically fallback to disk if system runs in a OOM situation? The API and storage type is unimportant as long as it can store basic Python types (str, int, list, date and ideally dict).

Comment: You could also just increase the size of your swap file until it was large enough and let the operating system decide what to put on disk and what to keep in RAM, and do the whole thing in memory.

Comment: In an OOM situation, your system has already been writing to disk, and you are now out of swap as well. The OOM killer will be on its way to start killing off your processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will go for the in memory solution and let the OS swap. I can still replace the storage component if this will be really a problem. Thanks agf.

Answer (score 1):

Python's built-in [`sqlite3`](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) caches file-system writes.